What is a good way to increment a FreeBSD package's version everytime I create it?
I'm creating a package using the pkg create command, I've specified the version in the +MANIFEST file. When I build/create the package next time, is there any way to increment the version automatically?
I went through pkg-create but couldn't find anything related to this.
